# html5 video preload

Tags: jquery, html, video, preload

Is it possible to preload an html video?  Note: the  tag is created dynamicly later.

Currently I can do this with images by creating a hidden div and putting all the images in there.  Then when I create the need  later the image does not need to be reloaded.

When this is done with a video tag, the browser still loads the video from the beginning when the  element is created.

I saw this: https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/html5Preloader.js, but it does not seem to work with videos.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: What about `preload="auto"` attribute?

Comment: You might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: Brett, this is about video, not images.

Answer (score 6):

Try this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" **preload="auto"**>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.webM" type="video/webM" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: This doesnt work on IE ;), for this you can use some player(simply inclusion of a .js). They have a fallbak of flash for IE use [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) & [JW Player Preload](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/preload)

Njoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in IE, some of the videos are display:none, and when I show them IE doesn't show first frame...

I used the following code to solve it,
when I show the hidden videos I call preloadAllVisible()

```
var preloadAllVisible = function() {
    $("video:visible").each(preload);
}
var preload = function(key, vid) {
    vid.play(); 
    setTimeout("pausevid("+key+")",100);
}

var pausevid = function(key) {
    vid =$("video:visible")[key];
    vid.pause();
    vid.currentTime = 0;
}
```