# I want to add an image to the specific section used in the html code whenever the screen size is resized to mobile view using media query

Tags: css, html, media-queries

How to add an image as a background using media queries to the section id= "vid" and hide the background video running on it.
My code HTML code is shown below

```
<section id="vid" class="vidd">
<video  playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="css\img_forest1.jpg" id="bgvd">
<source src="video\Love-Coding.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</section>
```

and CSS code is shown below

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
video { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    #vid { 
        background: url(img_forest.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your background image into `<section>` separately.

HTML

```
<section id="vid" class="vidd">
  <img src="css\img_forest1.jpg" class="image1"/>
  <video  playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="css\img_forest1.jpg" id="bgvd">
    <source src="video\Love-Coding.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.image1{ display: none; }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
 video { display: none; }
.image1 { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: Since the video is hidden, it will automatically load in the background. Is there any way that video should not load in the background

Comment: @Darshantheerth, have you tried adding 'controls preload="none"' to your video element? Here is some info on it: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp . The only downside is it is not supported in EI.

Comment: @EliaWeiss had a good JQuery answer as well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873562/html5-video-preload